# Theorem 10.38 Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

> **Theorem 10.38**
>
> Suppose $E$ is a convex open set in $\Bbb R^{n}$, $f \in C^{1}$, $p$ is an integer, $1\leq p \leq n$ and $(D_{j}f)(x)=0$ ($p<j \leq n ,x\in E$)
>
> Then there exists an $F \in C^{1}$ such that $$ (D_{p}F)(x)=f(x), (D_{j}F)(x)=0$$ if $p<j\leq n ,x \in E$
>
> **Proof**: Write $x=(x',x_{p},x'')$, where $x'=(x_{1},\dots,x_{p-1})$, $x''=(x_{p+1},\dots ,x_{n})$. When $p=1$, $x'$ is absent and when $p=n$, $x''$ is absent. Let $V$ be the set of all ($x',x_{p}$) such that $(x',x_{p},x'') \in E$ for some $x''$. Being a projection of $E$, $V$ is **convex open set** in $\Bbb R^{p}$. Since $E$ is **convex** and $(D_{j}f)(x)=0$ for $p<j\leq n$,$f(x)$ does not depend on $x''$. Hence there's a function $\phi$ with domain $V$ s.t $f(x)=\phi(x',x_{p})$, for all $x\in E$.
>
> If $p$=1, $V$ is a segment in $\Bbb R^{1}$. Pick $c \in V$ and define $$F(x)=\int_{c}^{x_{1}} \phi (t) dt$$
>
> If $p$>1, let $U$ be the set of all $x'\in \Bbb R^{p-1}$ such that $(x,x_{p}) \in V$ for some $x_{p}$. Then $U$ is a convex open set in $\Bbb R^{p-1}$ and there' a function $\alpha \in C^{1}$ such that $(x,\alpha (x')) \in V$ for all $x' \in U$. Define $$F(x)=\int_{\alpha (x')}^{x_{p}} \phi (x',t) dt$$

My question is that, what role does convexity play in this proof? It seems that even $E$ is not convex, we can still get the same result.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The role of convexity is that allows you to have a set of directions to take partial derivatives along lines.

Comment: I think the set being open allows us to have a set of directions to take partial derivatives along lines

Comment: Take $\mathbb{R}^2.$ Perhaps it's easier to see the point with an example. Take two disconnected open sets, $U_1, U_2$ on the $(x,y)$ plane. With $p=1,$ the condition $D_2f=0$ then means that $f=g_1(x)$ on $U_1$ and $f=g_2(x)$ on $U_2.$ However, $f(x,y)$ definitely depends on $y$ if $g_1\neq g_2.$

Comment: I guess I should add that my answer only covers the bold. The reason you need convex, which is stronger than connected is for the last part about integrating along lines.

Comment: If we remove finite points from the line, we can still integrate the function along it, but the interval now is not convex, how do we explain this phenomenon?