# Why convex? In Theorem 10.38 Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, differential-forms

In Theorem 10.38 *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by W Rudin it states without an explanation that $E \subset \mathbb{R^n} $ the open domain of $f$ to be convex is necessary and sufficient for the following claim to hold :

If $1\le p\le n$ and $D_jf(x) =0$ for all $p <j \le n$ then $f$ does not depend on $x_{p+1}, \dots x_n$.

The book and comments in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3506662/theorem-10-38-rudin) gives examples of why $D_jf(x) =0$ is not enough to make $f$ independent of $x_j$ but how imposing E to be $convex$ is enough to make $f$ independent of $x_j$? If the answer is "
that allows you to have a set of directions to take partial derivatives along lines" how does this hint applies to my question, rigorously?

Comment: I don't think convexity is needed for showing independence of $f$ on $x_j$, $j > p$. It is needed to define the integral $F(\mathbf{x}) = \int_{\alpha(\mathbf{x}')}^{x_p} \phi(\mathbf{x}', t) dt$. We require that the set $\{(\mathbf{x}', t) : t\in [\alpha(\mathbf{x}'), x_p]\}$ lies in the domain of $f$ that is $E$.

Comment: @feynhat, the book says "since E is convex,.. f(x) doesn't depend on $x_p$....

Comment: Where did you read this equivalence. The theorem you quote says completely different things. What you write in the comment has nothing to do with the equivalence. Since $E$ is convex, $E$ is connected and, therefore...

Comment: @Kosh, the book in example 10.36 and 10.37 gives $\mathbb{R^n}-{\{0}\}$ as examples of $connected$ non convex domain that the theorem 10.38 does not hold

Comment: My bad. Convexity is indeed needed for independence. See exercise 10 in the previous chapter (9).

Comment: @L.G. you are confusing the meaning of necessary and sufficient condition. If it is convex the result holds. If it is not convex nothing can be said, it can hold or not, and he gives examples of nonconvex domains where it does not hold. But there are also examples of nonconvex domains where the theorem holds.

Comment: @Kosh, yes I mixed things up! But still I don't know why if it convex the claim must hold? That is where exactly convexity is applied?

Comment: @feynhat, exercise 10 says there can be weaker condition but it doesn't say what? Still I don't understand explicit use of convexity?

Comment: @L.G. If there was no condition on the domain, would you still be able to make that independence claim? No. Convexity is what allows us to make that claim.

Comment: @L.G. You can further weaken that condition, but that will only guarantee that independence on a larger class of domains. Here, you have one more thing to care about (apart from independence), and that is the integral $F(\mathbf{x})$ should make sense, and for that you will need convexity.

Comment: @feynhat I did the exercise you mentioned, things are more clear now! Thanks :)

Comment: The independence from the variables holds in every open and connected set. Meaning that the function will be constant in any connected component of the "slices" of the open set with the direction in which the partial derivative is zero. But to find a "primitive" (as in the Theorem you quote) one needs something more. Rudin's use convexity, but this is only a sufficient condition.

Comment: @Kosh Thanks. To L.G., this ^, is the weakened condition that your looking for. More precisely, if $\partial f /\partial x_1$ vanishes and if you can join all $(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$ with $(x_1', x_2, \dots, x_n)$ by a straight line, then, $f$ is independent of $x_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $D_1f = 0$. If $(a, x_2, ..., x_n)$ and $(b, x_2, ..., x_n)\in E$, then the segment from $(a, x_2, ..., x_n)$ to $(b, x_2, ..., x_n)$ is contained in $E$. Now, by the mean-value theorem,
$$f(b, x_2, ..., x_n) - f(a, x_2, ..., x_n) = D_1f(\theta, x_2, ..., x_n)(b - a) = 0,$$
hence $f$ does not depend on $x_1$. (Here, after fixing $x_2, ..., x_n$ we thought of $f$ as a single-variable function, and we needed $E$ to be convex, so the function would be defined on the segment, so we could use the mean-value theorem).